# How to update all string into JSON array

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I'm looking for a way to update or better in my case concatenate each value into a JSON array. All the value are string.
I know that in simpler case I could do, to replace, something like:

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE('[1, 2, 3]', '$[0]', 9) AS 'Result';
```

that would replace the first field with 9; but there's a way to concatenate each value with a fixed string? I know that this is not correct but something like:

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE('[1, 2, 3]', '$[*]', concat($[*], 'fixed')) AS 'Result';
```

to get

```
'["1fixed", "2fixed", "3fixed"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tag the version of the DBMS please ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sorry I forgot to do it when I published the question but it's done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query which includes some JSON functions while extracting the elements of the array through using a kind of row generating technique such as

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                     JSON_EXTRACT(
                                  JSON_REPLACE(json, 
                                               j, 
                                               CONCAT(JSON_EXTRACT(json,j),'fixed')
                                               ), 
                                               j
                                 )
                     ) AS Result
  FROM
  (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, json, CONCAT('$[',@i-1,']') AS j                 
     FROM t
     JOIN (SELECT @i := 0 FROM t) AS k
     JOIN information_schema.tables ) AS jj
  WHERE i <= JSON_LENGTH(json)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=86f896e0fb1d1d9b84df3124a36d55bd)</kbd>

provided the version of the DB is at least 5.7

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> select json_arrayagg(concat(val, 'fixed')) as result 
  from json_table('[1, 2, 3]', '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')) as j;
+--------------------------------+
| result                         |
+--------------------------------+
| ["1fixed", "2fixed", "3fixed"] |
+--------------------------------+
```

MySQL 8.0 is required for the JSON_TABLE() function. MySQL 5.7 or later is required for the JSON_ARRAYAGG() function.

If this seems complicated, sorry, but it's a consequence of storing data as a JSON string, and then trying to use SQL expressions on the values within the string. It's bound to be awkward, because you're implementing an antipattern called the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

This would be far easier if you did not store data as a JSON array, but stored data in a normal form, with one value per row.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot apply this to my case due to version constraint but anyhow your point is very interesting. JSON storage was a requirement but I get your point. 
Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Nearly every case I've seen of storing JSON in MySQL has led to tears.

Comment: This is useful, however I still wonder how to join with actual table to read json from existing column 

Comment: @hejdav, Yes, the documentation is pretty unclear on this. I filed a bug report with MySQL to improve the documentation, but they refused to change it. See the suggested example I posted here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102089